# Why is $y'=\frac{y}{x}$ exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A well known theorem states that differential form $m dx+n dy=0$ is exact iff $\partial_y m=\partial_x n$. But why is $y'=\frac{y}{x}$ ($\equiv xdy-ydx=0$) exact?

Comment: If you say it is exact, how can you find the solution according to  steps of exact equation

Comment: see $\partial_y m=-\partial_x n$

Comment: I asked this question because l see in a book. (In book: First show that this equation is exact then solve it.)

Comment: this $ xdy+ydx=0$ is exact but $ xdy-ydx=0$ not exact

Comment: A similar situation, $y'=\frac{y\cos x+\sin y+y}{\sin x+x\cos y+x}$ is this exact?

Answer (score 1):

Differential equations aren't exact or inexact; expressions of the form $F(x,\,y)dx+G(x,\,y)dy$ are. The difference is crucial, because the choice of $F,\,G$ equivalent to a given equation won't be unique. What's exact in this case is $d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\frac{1}{y}dx-\frac{x}{y^2}dy$, which is $0$ for solutions of $y^\prime=\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

see what happens if you assume it exact
$$\int xdy=xy+f(x)$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(xy+f(x))=y+f'(x)=-y$$
$$f'(x)=-2y$$
that is impossible, so the equation is not exact